# Объединение условий в re

Tags: python, re

нужно убрать из списка все лишние пробелы, цифры, \n и тп, на данный момент получается так, что остается ФИО, которое слипается и нужно проставить пробелы перед заглавными буквами кроме фамилии, помогите, пожалуйста

```
name_n_group = {re.sub(r"[^А-Яа-я]| *([ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ]) *", "|\1 ", page[k][2]) : re.sub(r"-", "", group_number)}
```

в данном отрывке из кода я пытаюсь объединить фио студента и его номер группы, получается, что вложенный список, отвечающий за номер группы работает корректно, а вот с фио не получается сделать
[image: вот пример вывода]

```py
worksheet = sh.sheet1  # получаем первый лист
page = worksheet.get_values()

group_number = page[0][0]
main_spisok = {}
name_n_group = {}

print("\n", page)

for k in range(1, len(page)):
    if (('Учебный год' in page[k][0]) or ('ДИСЦИПЛИНА' in page[k][0]) or ('ФИО' in page[k][0])):
        print('No')

    else:
        #for i in range(0,1):
        name_n_group = {re.sub(r"[^А-Яа-я]", "", page[k][2]) : re.sub(r"-", "", group_number)}

        main_spisok[k] = {page[k][0] : name_n_group}
        print('Yes')

print("\n\n", "spisok= ", main_spisok)
```

Comment: Разместите, пожалуйста, первоначальные строки, которые вы объединяете, только не в виде картинки а как текст.

Comment: {3: {'Технология облачных вычислений': {'АфанасьевВладиславАлексеевич': 'БИК1801'}}, 6: {'Компоненты системы оптической связи': {'ПасечникНиколайОлеговичРябининОлегСергеевич': 'БИК1801'}}} . 3 и 6 - из-за цикла у меня создается ключ, который я не могу убрать, вместо него ключом должен быть предмет, а значение- список из фамилии и номера группы

Comment: Это вам такой текст дали? Или он получился в результате каких-то действий?

Comment: worksheet = sh.sheet1  # получаем первый лист
page = worksheet.get_values()
 текст- все значения с гугл таблицы
если в кратце, то я перебираю таблицу- по строкам формируются вложенные списки, которые находятся в page, потом я просматриваю их и выбираю предмет и фамилию, которая в той же строке

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы не ту проблему решаете. Вам просто надо правильно прочитать гугл таблицу.

Comment: Я уже задумывался о том, что делаю что-то не так, но отсутствие опыта сказывается. Первый раз делаю нечто подобное, да и в программировании я новичок, какой можете дать совет?

Comment: Используйте стандартный API Google https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?hl=ru

Comment: уже использую, через сервисный аккаунт и json файл открываю эту таблицу

Comment: Картинка в вопросе это часть полученного json-а?

Comment: нет, это main_spisok (последняя сточка кода)